# Assert type based on a string?

Tags: go

Suppose I have the following:

```
type T struct { Name string }
```

Then I create a var of type T:

```
thing := T{"Hello World"}
```

I then reflect the type:

```
t := reflect.TypeOf(thing) // main.T
```

Then I pass `t` in to a method that accepts an interface, is there any way I can then say, in that method, that the accepted `interface{}` is of type `main.T` if I have that string?

The use case is I have a json string that fits a type. I have a string of that type (`main.T`) and I want to be able to create a new variable that is of type `main.t` when I only know of the string, `main.T` then marshal the data to that new variable.

Comment: I don't understand. Variables appear in source code, they are verified at compile time. There's no such thing as a dynamic variable (or variables of dynamic types). Why does the variable type even matter? What are you trying to do downstream?

Answer (score 0):

The Go runtime does not provide a way to create a value given the name of a type, but that's something you can implement in the application:

```
var types = map[string]reflect.Type{
    "main.T": reflect.TypeOf((*T)(nil)).Elem(),
}
```

You can create a new value given the name using:

```
v := reflect.New(types[name]).Interface()
```

This assumes that name is a valid name. You may want to check for the case where types[name] == nil.

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/mnSMgc4GVR)

You can also do this without reflection:

```
var types = map[string]func() interface{} {
    "main.T": func() interface{} { return &T{} }
}

v := types[name]()
```